# Facebook authentication without storing an access token?

Tags: facebook, security, authentication

I'm writing a [React](https://reactjs.org/) app that needs to have a login with Facebook button.

The React app is already communicating with a PHP API that already has a system in place for registering and logging in users with a username/password. The API generates a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and sends it to the front-end, which stores it in local storage and uses it to authenticate the user on subsequent API calls.

I've gotten my front-end app to the point where I'm successfully opening the FB permissions dialog, and receiving a response from FB that contains a `userID` & `accessToken` after the user grants permission.

My question is:

***Do I need to store the FB `accessToken` if I don't need to access FB's API afterwards? Can I simply store the `userID` and use it for authentication?***

My proposed auth flow would look something like this:

1. User clicks login with Facebook button, grants permissions in the dialog.
2. My React app sends the `userID` to my PHP API.
3. The API looks up the user in our DB by FB `userID`. If it finds one, it sends back a valid JWT, logging in the user.
4. If no user is found, the `userID` will be stored in the app's state, and it will begin the registration process, passing the FB `userID` along with the rest of the registration data when the user completes registration. The API then generates a JWT and proceeds with login like normal.

Would this be wildly insecure and a would be hackers easiest-day-ever?

Or is it safe to implement?

Comment: No, that’s not safe, because nothing is stopping me from sending any user id I like to your server. Send the access token, and use it on the server side to make an API request, to get the user id. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checktoken

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if it's just me but I find the Facebook docs kind of hard to navigate. Could totally just be me.